# CommonDomain / EventStore with Raven persistance for multi-tenant app

Tags: ravendb, cqrs, neventstore

*How should I setup EventStore's RavenPersistence in a multi-tenant application?*

I have an Azure worker role that processes commands received through service bus.
Each message may belong to a different tenant. The actual tenant is sent in the message header, which means that I know which database to use only after I receive each message.

I'm using CommonDomain so my command handlers have `IRepository` injected.

Right now I build a new store while processing each message (I set DefaultDatabase) but I have a feeling this may not be the most optimal way.

- Is there a way to create a single event store and then just switch databases?
- If not, can I cache the stores for each tenant?
- Do you know about any multi-tenant sample that uses EventStore with RavenDB?

Answer (score 1):

We do exactly the same - spawn new instance of EventStore for every request. JOliver EventStore was designed without multi-tenancy support in mind. So this is the only way ...

Comment: Would you mind sharing a bit of code that performs initialization? Do you use any DI container? If yes, do you just re-register `IStoreEvents`?

Comment: I am too would love to hear how you achieved this.. I am at that point where I need to segregate each client to their own ES. Thanks